# loading assembly GAC_MSIL

Tags: c#, .net

I have the problem in my project ,I must load  the assembly .
my problem is "impossible de charger l'assembly nom_dll" I am working with c# and framework 4 in my project  I have     v4.0
I use gacutil / if nom_dll to  installe my  dll  in GAC ,it is install in path C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stackoverflow ! can you please share some or all of the code that's giving you this error ? 

this will help other reproduce your issue or pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is for an ASP.NET application there are 2 options:

1. The new dll is in your **bin** directory but in your web.config you should not include the version, culture and PublicKeyToken details in your reference.

or

2. Your new dll is in the **GAC** (C:\Windows\Assembly) and your web.config should contain at least a valid PublicKeyToken.

```xml
<compilation targetFramework="4.0">
     <assemblies>
        <add assembly="SomeNS.SomeDllName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=568C4712810GD043"/>
```

Comment: my  dll  existe in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL and i have targetFramework="4.0"    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion> this balise existe in  communication.csproj

Answer (score 0):

I have been taught that there are essentially two GACS:

1. One at "C:\Windows\assembly", which is for .Net Framework 3.x and lower, and
2. One at "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\", which is for .Net Framework 4.x and above.

We are going through this right now, with some discussion as to which GAC to use. Our folder structure under "C:\Windows\assembly" only has a "download" folder, which is empty.

The folder structure under "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\" is:

1. "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32"
2. "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64"
3. "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL"

Our latest .DLLs are in the "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL".

I hope this helps.

Randy